# How to scroll to bottom of page when postback finish in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

How to scroll to bottom of page when postback finish in asp.net?

I have many details in page when I click "Show Detail" in master detail, this page show many data in my page. So how to to scroll to bottom of page automatically?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could register the a javascript to move the scroll to the position of some control that you want, like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            RegisterStartupScript("ScrollScript", "document.getElementById('objectId').scrollIntoView(true);");
        }
    }
```

Changing the objectId in the script for the Id of the object you want to scroll to.

As noted by Guy Starbuk in the comments, `RegisterStartupScript` is deprecated in .Net 4 and now the recommended way to register a script is:

```
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "ScrollScript", "document.getElementById('objectId').scrollIntoVie‌​w(true)", true);
```

Comment: This is a great answer and worked for me -- something to note is that RegisterStartupScript is deprecated in .NET 4, I used the following:

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "ScrollScript", "document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_postSaveMessageDiv').scrollIntoView(true)", true);

Answer (score 14):

from [Hosam Kamel's page](http://weblogs.asp.net/hosamkamel/archive/2007/09/07/maintain-scroll-position-after-postbacks-in-asp-net-2-0.aspx)

To maintain the scroll position for the large web page you can use on of these methods :

1- use Web.config page section `<pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" />`

: this will maintains the scroll positions for all the web site pages.

2- in the page declaration  `<%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>` : this will maintains the scroll position for this page only.

3- programmatically from code behind `System.Web.UI.Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;`  : this will maintains the scroll position for this page only (the same as page declration).

Comment: How to use its i add <%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %> but not work to bottom?

Comment: that current scroll position?

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood the problem. I had a similar situation where the user would scroll to the bottom of the page, do a post back and would lost the scroll position.Now I understand that the user directly should go to the bottom of the page after postback

Answer (score 2):

In asp.net web pages you can add an OnClientClick event to the control causing the server post back to scroll the page to the bottom.

```
<asp:Button ID="MyButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="MyButton_Click" OnClientClick="window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);" />
```

Comment: Important to note that this seems to be the only one of the proposed solutions that work inside of an updatepanel. This doesn't help the OP but may help somebody coming to this question from google, like me.

Answer (score 0):

Create an anchor on the page, then on onload:

```
window.location.href = "#myanchor"
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing missing from the answers here is a delay. It's all well and good if there is no change in the height of the web page during load. But if there are a lot of images and your trying scroll past them; they can bump your view back up again.

What is needed is a window.onload function call:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "ScrollScript", "window.onload = function() {document.getElementById('objectid').scrollIntoView(true);}", true);
```